# postfix default_process_limit not changing

Tags: postfix

I am trying to change the default_process_limit to 200 but it does not seem to work.

```
# postconf -e default_process_limit=200
# service postfix reload 
# postconf -d default_process_limit   
default_process_limit = 100
```

Any idea why this is?

Answer (score 2):

"-d" displays the default setting, so just "postconf default_process_limit" to get the current setting.